# Web Bluetooth Big issue: Chrome is not finding any devices

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, web-bluetooth, android-chrome

I'm using Web Bluetooth technology,I'm trying to connect  an Android 6.0.1(Galaxy J7 prime) with an another Android device  6.0.1(Galaxy J5) in chrome (Version 60.0.311),it doest not scaning any device.
How do I list the nearby or paired Bluetooth devices on Chrome mobile for Android?
I searched Bluetooth device natively,it connected automatically and showed the list. But it does not search any device in Chrome. I tried many sample Web Bluetooth Project,it's not scanning any devices on chrome browser. Give some working sample project.

Note: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html?allDevices=true

I tried the above link ,it did not show any devices on chrome so that i can't able to finish my project . please guide me for fix this issue

Comment: What happens when you click the button on that sample page? Nothing at all? What error is reported in "Live Output"?

Answer (score 5):

Ensure your device's Bluetooth and Location settings are on. Check that you haven't denied Location permission to Chrome in the [Android App Settings](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6293419?hl=en).

Navigate to `chrome://bluetooth-internals`.

1. It should show the adapter details.
2. Select 'Devices' and start a scan.

See also https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs to find android logs and file a bug if you belive it is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [documentation](https://medium.com/@urish/start-building-with-web-bluetooth-and-progressive-web-apps-6534835959a6) which stated that in order to use Web Bluetooth in Chrome, there are two options:

1. The website has to be a part of a public experiment (“Origin Trial”) Chrome is running. You can register on [this page](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfO0_ptFl8r8G0UFhT0xhV17eabG-erUWBDiKSRDTqEZ_9ULQ/viewform?entry.631548922&entry.1000000&entry.1000001&entry.1999497328=Web+Bluetooth+(Experimenting+until+late+January+2017)&entry.1000005). Once you enlist your website, all your visitors will be able to use Web Bluetooth from your site if they have a supported device / operating system.
2. You can enable Web Bluetooth for all sites by going to chrome flags. Simply type “chrome://flags” in the address bar, search for “Web Bluetooth” and enable it (also applies to Android 6 users).

If no devices show up, make sure that both Bluetooth and Location Services are turned on. On Android 6, both Bluetooth and Location access are required in order to scan for BLE devices, and that no other app is connected the target device. BLE devices stop advertising their services once some app is connected to them.

Comment: Chrome for Android 6 has had support for Web Bluetooth since February 2017 (Chrome 56). The posters Chrome app appears to be up to date (as of today v60).